# Set decimal fraction number digits dynamically in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display the `row_Debit` fraction digests depends on `@fractionsNumber` parameter, although I declared the column as `Row_Credit decimal(18,3)`, how can I do that?

```
@fractionsNumber = 2 ;

Declare @InvoiceDetails as table(Row_Credit decimal(18,3) Null)

insert into @InvoiceDetails( Row_Debit )
Select amount as row_Debit
from Invoices
```

Comment: @Alaa : it's quite unclear what are you asking ?

Comment: In the direct case, my table will display  "Row_Debit" column with 3 fraction digits, but I need to let them 2 or 5 digits or any number dynamically @Vijaykumar Hadalgi

Comment: `SELECT round(row_Debit,@fractionsNumber),other stuff... FROM table...` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `STR` to display a fixed number of digits:

```
SELECT STR(Row_Debit,18,@fractionsNumber) FROM @InvoiceDetails
```

But be aware that you then get back a `VARCHAR` type instead of a numeric type.